# How to prove the triangle inequality for hermitian angle between vectors in a complex vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that I have a vector space defined over complex numbers. I can calculate the hermitian angle between two vectors as following:

$$
\theta_H (\vec{u},\vec{v}) = \cos^{-1} \left(\frac{|\vec{u}.\vec{v}^*|}{||u||.||v||}\right)
$$

How do I prove the following triangle inequality for $\theta_H$?

$$
\theta_H(\vec{u},\vec{v}) \leq \theta_H(\vec{u},\vec{w}) + \theta_H(\vec{v},\vec{w})
$$

In case that the vector space is over real numbers, you can take the span of the three vectors and project that space onto a 3d euclidean space and prove the inequality in 3d euclidean space. But I am not sure how to do something like that for complex numbers. Is there a similar approach that I can follow in this case? Or something completely different?

Comment: It's not true, even over the reals. Take $u$ and $v$ that are not perpendicular, and take $w$ to be perpendicular to both of them.

Comment: In your example, $\theta(u,w) + \theta(v,w) = 90$ degrees. And the angle $\theta(u,v)$ cannot be more than 180 degrees. So, it does satisfy triangle inequality.

Comment: In that case, you seem to have the wrong formula. In the real case, you'd be wanting$$\theta(u, v) = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{u \cdot v}{\|u\| \|v\|}\right).$$I'm not certain what would work in the complex case, but if you take the absolute values, it means you cannot have angles between $90^\circ$ and $180^\circ$.

Comment: I missed the $\cos^{-1}$ in my question. Thanks for that. you are right that we can't have angles between 90 and 180 degrees. But that doesn't tell us much about whether the inequality is valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up coincidentally solving your problem as part of my research, so I thought I'd come back and share.

We might as well assume that our vectors are unit vectors. Suppose $x, y, z$ are unit vectors, and let
$$G = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \langle x, y \rangle & \langle x, z \rangle \\ \langle y, x \rangle & 1 & \langle y, z \rangle \\ \langle z, x \rangle & \langle z, y \rangle & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that $G$ is a [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix), and hence positive-semidefinite (also: positive definite if and only if $x, y, z$ are linearly independent). Thus $\det G \ge 0$, i.e.
$$1 + 2\Re(\langle x, y\rangle \langle y, z\rangle \langle z, x\rangle) - |\langle x, y\rangle|^2 - |\langle y, z\rangle|^2 - |\langle z, x\rangle|^2 \ge 0.$$
Note that this is equivalent to
$$(1 - |\langle x, y \rangle|^2)(1 - |\langle y, z \rangle|^2) \ge |\langle x, y\rangle \langle y, z\rangle - \langle z, x \rangle|^2,$$
by expanding both sides and cancelling the common term of $|\langle x, y \rangle|^2 |\langle y, z \rangle|^2$. Taking the square root of both sides, we get
$$|\langle x, y\rangle \langle y, z\rangle| - |\langle z, x \rangle| \le |\langle x, y\rangle \langle y, z\rangle - \langle z, x \rangle| \le \sqrt{1 - |\langle x, y \rangle|^2}\sqrt{1 - |\langle y, z \rangle|^2},$$
thus
$$|\langle z, x \rangle| \ge |\langle x, y\rangle \langle y, z\rangle| - \sqrt{1 - |\langle x, y \rangle|^2}\sqrt{1 - |\langle y, z \rangle|^2}.$$
Note that $\cos(\theta_H(p, q)) = |\langle p, q\rangle|$ for unit vectors $p, q$, so this inequality becomes
\begin{align*}
\cos(\theta_H(x, z)) &\ge \cos(\theta_H(x, y))\cos(\theta_H(y, z)) - \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(\theta_H(x, y))}\sqrt{1 - \cos^2(\theta_H(y, z))} \\
&= \cos(\theta_H(x, y))\cos(\theta_H(y, z)) - \sin(\theta_H(x, y))\sin(\theta_H(y, z)) \\
&= \cos(\theta_H(x, y) + \theta_H(y, z)).
\end{align*}
Note that $\cos$ is strictly monotone decreasing on $[0, \pi]$, on which we may find $\theta_H(x, y) + \theta_H(y, z)$ and $\theta_H(x, z)$, hence
$$\theta_H(x, z) \le \theta_H(x, y) + \theta_H(y, z).$$
We also get that, if we achieve equality, then $\det G = 0$, and $x, y, z$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Does the above result hold for Euclidean angle, $\theta_E=Re(\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{y})/||\mathbf{x}||||\mathbf{y}||$ of complex vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$?